# how to filter an array based on values from another array in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I need to reduce array 1 in a such a way that - array 1 should contain only those items whose 'friendlyName' matches the values of array 2.

I tried the following code but did not work. Can any one please help me -

```
arrray2.map(asdf => {
    console.log("asdf",asdf)
    console.log("dum",array1)
    array1.filter(dat => dat.friendlyName.includes(asdf)).map(d => (
     
      console.log( "d",d)
   
  ))
})
```

Array 1 -

```
renderTaskQueues 
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
accountSid: "AC90e9fc43df2675a1a2de215c0e78fc74"
assignmentActivityName: null
friendlyName: "CUSTOMER_SERVICE_SP"
__proto__: Object
1:
accountSid: "AC90e9fc43df2675a1a2de215c0e78fc74"
assignmentActivityName: "Offline"
friendlyName: "CUSTOMER_SERVICE_EN"
__proto__: Object
2:
accountSid: "AC90e9fc43df2675a1a2de215c0e78fc74"
friendlyName: "Survey"
__proto__: Object
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Array 2 -

```
agentQueuesArray 
(2) ["Customer_Service_EN", "Customer_Service_SP"]
0: "Customer_Service_EN"
1: "Customer_Service_SP"
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: `array1.filter(it => array2.map(aqa => aqa.toLowerCase()).includes(it.friendlyName.toLowerCase()))`, is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

It is not matching because the case is different. You can do something like this:

```
arrray2.map(asdf => {
    console.log("asdf",asdf)
    console.log("dum",array1)
    array1.filter(dat => dat.friendlyName.toUpperCase() === asdf.toUpperCase()).map(d => (
     
      console.log( "d",d)
   
  ))
})
```